# WPF MVVM Registration Login

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm new to "wpf". I'm making some demo application. Have multiple windows inside Views Folder(Employee, Items...). I want to have navigation menu in the Main Window and on click to display the other windows - BUT with MVVM pattern. I've watched some tutorials about PRISM regions, but still I cannot understand - **is it possible to put other **Windows**(from the Views folder, not User Controls) inside Main window?** and if it is can someone point me to the right resources?
Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not meant as a tutorial hub. If you want help, please show some code and ask a specific question or state a specific problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# WPF Child Windows inside Main Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30407331/c-sharp-wpf-child-windows-inside-main-window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to put other **Windows(from the Views folder, not User Controls) inside Main window?**

No, a `System.Windows.Window` cannot be a child of another `System.Windows.Window`.

The contents of the regions should be defined as `UserControls`.

You should just be able to move the contents of your windows to the user controls.